# Python, I am coding a remote shell maker and keep on running into syntax errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, syntax-error

```
import os
os.system("touch shellback.py")
a = raw_input("IP of The Listener(you)> ")
print "Set ip to "+ a +""
file = open("shellbackdoor.py", "a")
file.write("from socket import *\n")
file.write("HOST = '"+ a +"'\n");
file.close()
file = open("shellback.py", "a")
file.write("PORT = 443\n")
print "You might to to port forward your router to the port 443"
file.write("s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)\n")
file.write("s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)\n")
file.write("s.bind((HOST, PORT))\n")
file.write("print 'Listening on "+ a +":%s' % str(PORT)\n")
file.write("s.listen(10)\n")
file.write("conn, addr = s.accept()\n")
file.write("print 'Connected by', addr\n")
file.write("data = conn.recv(1024)\n")
file.write("while 1:\n")
file.write("     command = raw_input("> ")")
file.write("     conn.send(command)\n")
file.write("     if command == "quit":\n")
file.write("          break\n")
file.write("     data = conn.recv(1024)\n")
file.write("     print data\n")
file.write("conn.close()\n")
```

I keep on running into a syntax error on

```
file.write("     if command == "quit":\n")
```

put I don't know why

It used two lines above on

```
file.write("     command = raw_input("Insert your command or quit>")")
```

but it stopped the error after I changed it to

```
file.write("     command = raw_input("> ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it right . But you need to escape the double quotes like i have shown below

**line from your code :**

```
file.write("     if command == "quit":\n")
```

**Fixed Line**

```
file.write("     if command == \"quit\":\n")
```

hope this helps